# PactSwift how to build on CI

Tags: swift, pact

PactSwift:
we are unable to generate pact file while running on real time device, so we planned to generate pact file using CI.
Please share the information about how to generate and push the Pact file using CI.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The steps for the consumer pipeline are like this:

- run consumer tests. You should know the exact command here

  - Make sure you understand where are pacts are located after the tests run
- use [PactBroker CLI to publish pacts](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker-client#publish) to the broker: `pact-broker publish ...`

  - Make sure you know here: pact broker URL, the way how to call it (auth)

That's a first part, when provider part is ready ready about `can-i-deploy` and there is more